# Using Lookup function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am currently automating a sales report with VBA and I am having trouble with inserting a formula using VBA with a dynamic range. My Formula with Lookup finds the last week that a client ordered.

The current week is the last week and is always the column prior to the Total column. I am having trouble referencing that last column with the current week.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(CL[@[Week 1]:[Week 17]]>0),COLUMN(CL[[#Headers],[Week 1]:[Week 17]]))
```

I wasn't sure how to reference using headers.
So the first part of my code finds the column number and using the column number I get the Letter reference. Not sure how to use the Letters with my `LOOKUP` formula

```
Sub LastOrder()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strSearchEnd As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim startingCol As Variant
    Dim endingCol As Variant
    Dim colFirstWeek As Variant
    Dim ColLastWeek As Variant
    Dim firstCheck As Variant
    Dim lastCheck As Variant

    'find the column number for week 1 and total 

    strSearch = "Week 1"
    strSearchEnd = "Total"  

    Set aCell = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        startingCol = aCell.Column
    End If

    Set endCell = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearchEnd, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not endCell Is Nothing Then
        endingCol = endCell.Column - 1  
        'this is used to get column number of current week 
    End If

    'Use letter reference 

    firstCheck = Split(Cells(, startingCol).Address, "$")(1)
    lastCheck = Split(Cells(,  endingCol).Address, "$")(1)

    Debug.Print (firstCheck)
    Debug.Print (lastCheck)

    Range("CL[Last Week Ordered]").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "LOOKUP(2,1/(firstCheck:lastCheck>0),COLUMN(firstCheck:lastCheck))
```

Comment: Honestly, when dealing with table formulas, I tend to store the formula in the workbook, then copy-paste it over. Usually gets the job done, with bonus table auto-fill kicking in. Also, in reading the question, I'd grab the ID of the prior week with VBA, then simply subtract 1 to get the prior week, then run the lookup directly aiming at the table you need, instead of looking it up

Comment: are you just trying to get the dynamic range of current row from `@[Week 1]:` to the column before last one ? Something like this `[@[Week 1]]:INDEX([@], , COLUMNS([@])-1)`

Comment: @Slai, Yes I need to reference the column that is one previous to the column header "Total"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula  :

```
=LOOKUP(2, 1 / ( [@[Week 1]]:INDEX([@], , COLUMNS([@]) - 1) > 0 ), 
         COLUMN( [@[Week 1]]:INDEX([@], , COLUMNS([@]) - 1) ) )
```

Few Excel Functions like `INDEX` and `OFFSET` return Range reference, so they can be used with the range operator `:`, and `Range("INDEX(A1:B1, 1, 1)")` in VBA.